# Wcf inherit and dynamic CreateChannel

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, inheritance

I have an issues on ihneritance on service when i called a dynamic `ChannelFactory`.

The structure of my project :
I have a class `ServiceBase` and an interface `IServiceBase` that is used in all WCF Service and Contract (2 separate projects).

`IServiceBase`

```
Imports System.ServiceModel

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IServiceBase

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Ping.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>Vrai.</returns>
    <OperationContract()>
    Function Ping() As Boolean
End Interface
```

`ServiceBase`

```
Public Class ServiceBase
    Implements IDisposable, IServiceBase

#Region "IServiceBase"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Ping.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' Vrai.
    ''' </returns>
    Public Function Ping() As Boolean Implements IServiceBase.Ping
        Return True
    End Function

#End Region
End Class
```

All `IFoo` inherit from `IServiceBase`.
All `Foo` ihnerit from `ServiceBase` and implement `IFoo`.

---

I have a TestController (client-side) that load all assembly of contracts to parse if it is alive.

So I take assembly by the type of one of my contracts (working well)

```
 Dim common As Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(Firma.Project.Services.Contracts.ICommon))
```

For each of them I determine if it's an interface and if it derived from `IServiceBase` (working well, but only with `IsAssignableFrom`, `GetMethod` don't return `Ping` from derived interface (works only with class)).

```
For Each ty As Type In common.GetTypes
                If ty.IsInterface AndAlso GetType(IServiceBase).IsAssignableFrom(ty) Then 
                    Try
                        Dim myInterfaceType As Type = ty

                        Dim value As String = String.Empty
                        If Not _dicEndPoints.TryGetValue(ty.FullName, value) Then
                            Continue For
                        End If
```

From this, I create dynamically my channel (seems working, i see well `ChannelFactory<IFoo>(endpointname)` in debug step)

```
                ' Type ChannelFactory<>.
                Dim factoryType = GetType(ChannelFactory(Of )).MakeGenericType(myInterfaceType)
                ' Constructeur ChannelFactory<IFoo>(endpointname)
                Dim factoryCtr = factoryType.GetConstructor(New Type() {GetType(String)})
                ' Invoke dynamic ChannelFactory<IFoo>(endpointname)
                Dim factory = factoryCtr.Invoke(New Object() {value})
                ' dynamic Create Channel 
                Dim channel = factory.CreateChannel()
```

But when I call the method `Ping`, it doesn't work

```
Dim retour As Object = channel.Ping()
```

I've got "public method Ping is not found".
Another method declared directly in `Foo` class are working and the method `Ping` is working well when I used Client Test WCF on `IFoo` Service.
So it mean that dynamic create of `ChannelFactory` is the issue, but I don't see how to make this.

Edit: answer can be translated in C# and response can be given in C#

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Maybe I'm not be clear on my question ?

Comment: Or VB.Net burns developer's eyes :)

Comment: Have you tried to create the factory like this:  Dim factoryCtr As ChannelFactory(Of IFoo) = New ChannelFactory(Of IFoo)?
Also, maybe you must provide more information when creating the channel, like Endpoint and Behavior.

Comment: I can't declare a ChannelFactory(Of myInterfaceType). If not, it will be more easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I'm assuming myInterfaceType is your interface implementing IServiceBase, and value is your endpoint name in your WCF config

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var factoryType = typeof(MyChannelFactory).GetMethod("CreateProxyChannel", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        var generic = factoryType.MakeGenericMethod(myInterfaceType);

        var result = generic.Invoke(null, new[] { value});

        var channel = (IServiceBase) result;

        var check = channel.Ping();
    }

}

class MyChannelFactory
{
    public static T CreateProxyChannel<T>(string endpointName)
    {
        ChannelFactory<T> factory = new ChannelFactory<T>(endpointName);

        return factory.CreateChannel();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working when I cast to IServiceBase. So it will be good for the behavior that I have need. But I'm asking ever on why I can't see base method on dynamic call (explicit cast to IFoo don't return base method).

Comment: Explicit cast to IFoo also works, since IFoo implements IServiceBase